# I want capture images from webcam using opencv at certain intervals

Tags: opencv

I tried using schedule. It works fine but the viewfinder of the webcam is stuck at the initial state so it produces only one image multiple times.

Any help?

```
import cv2
import time
import schedule

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("Webcam")

img_counter = 0


def capture():

    global img_counter

    img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)

    cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)

    print("screenshot taken")

    img_counter += 1



while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()

    if not ret:
        print("failed to grab frame")
        break

    cv2.imshow("test", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k % 256 == 27:
        print("closing the app")
        break

    else:
        schedule.every(5).seconds.do(capture)
        while 1:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

cam.release()

cam.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: As written, I think your code gets stuck in the `while 1` loop. So it should be calling `capture` every 5 seconds. However `capture` has no read statement. Read is only called once on the first loop of `while True`. To fix, you might want to move the `read` function to `capture`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are suffering from buffering. **OpenCV** `VideoCapture()` reads a few frames into a buffer - I think it is 5 but have not checked for a while and it may differ between platforms or versions.

There are a few possible work-arounds depending on your situation:

- call `read()` 4-5 times when you want a frame - it will only take a couple of hundred milliseconds
- call `grab()` either repeatedly in another thread or just before you want a frame
- reduce the size of the buffer so it can only hold a single frame.

Sorry for the somewhat woolly answer as I am not set up to test more at the moment.

Comment: Might not be this - OP is only reading from the camera once and reusing the result in the capture function...

Comment: @AKX You're probably right, I'm not sure what OP is really trying to achieve, so I'll leave it for a bit as a possible idea to consider and delete it if we work it out a better solution. Thanks for flagging it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code could be simplified to something like this while still retaining a near-realtime preview of the periodically saved images.

```
import cv2
import schedule

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow("Webcam")
img_counter = 0


def capture():
    global img_counter
    img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
    cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
    print("screenshot taken")
    img_counter += 1


# Set up schedule before loop

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(capture)


while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()

    if not ret:
        print("failed to grab frame")
        break

    cv2.imshow("test", frame)
    schedule.run_pending()

    k = cv2.waitKey(100)  # 1/10 sec delay; no need for separate sleep

    if k % 256 == 27:
        print("closing the app")
        break

cam.release()
cam.destroyAllWindows()
```